# How to make a hashcode(integer value) positive

Tags: java, hash, bitwise-operators

```
int x = 10; int y = (x.hashcode() & 0xfffffff);
```

How does the above code always make `y` **positive**? Thanks!

Comment: If it's meant to be a hash code, why do you want to ensure it's positive? As for why it's doing that already - you're keeping the bottom 32 bits; the top 4 bits will always be cleared. Any `int` with the top bit clear is non-negative. You could achieve this without losing as much information by using `x.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff`(aka `x.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he is asking why the bitwise operation will get you a positive value.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi: Well that's what the body of the question says (and I explain in the comment) but the *title* of the question asks how to get a positive value.

Comment: @JonSkeet: `If it's meant to be a hash code, why do you want to ensure it's positive?` I don't know the OP's motivation, but a common reason would be to use the hash value as an index into a table (i.e. a hash table).

Comment: @LarsH: That's normally done with a bitmask for the table length (which is typically a power of 2). You're not going to use the hash code *directly* as an index unless you've really got a table with 2^31 entries...

Comment: @JonSkeet: So you agree there's motivation for making the hash code positive... you would just do it at the same time as you mask it to table length. Not *directly* as in index, no. But when performance is less important than simplicity, you might easily have a table whose size isn't a power of two. In that case it's common to use `% tableLength`, and then you run into Java's negative results from `%`. One solution is to first ensure the hash value is positive.

Comment: A good example of a hash table where you can't bitmask the index to put it into the exact range of the table length is in http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html. The table length is not guaranteed to be a power of 2 because the initial capacity of the table is supplied by the user. And no attempt is made at keeping powers of 2. The default initial capacity is 11, and when overflow occurs, `newCapacity = (oldCapacity << 1) + 1`. Hence `index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length`.

Comment: @LarsH: I agreed there's motivation for converting an arbitrary hash code into a table index. Sure, if you *just* use `%` on its own with negative input, you'll give negative values, but there are multiple ways round that. It's unfortunate that the OP never responded to the comments, including not explaining why the title of the question and the body seem quite different.

Comment: Using a value as a table index requires that it be non-negative (which is what the OP's question meant by "positive").

Comment: I'm sorry the question title and body are different. I was looking at the HashMap implementation(hash method) from http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/SeparateChainingHashST.java.html
My actual doubt was with bit wise operation only. It is clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`x.hashcode() & 0xfffffff` will turn the sign bit off. `Math.abs` is not used here because it returns negative if `x.hashCode` is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which will make the  `hashtable's` array throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` which is not something you want.

From @JonSkeet comment: *It doesn't just turn the sign bit off, it clears the next three bits as well*.

But with hash codes we deal with collisions all the time, so it is considered fine.

Comment: It doesn't *just* turn the sign bit off, mind you - it clears the next three bits as well...

Comment: Sleiman, could you explain a bit more about the inner workings of that `x.hashcode() & 0xfffffff` statement? What is happening exactly under the hood?

Comment: @Sahand see D. Kalb's answer below explaining bitwise AND and what's happening particularly in this case in a bit more detail

Answer (score 15):

The `&` will perform a bitwise AND operation. That means it will take the bits of the first number, in your case the hashcode, and the second number, in your case `0xFFFFFFF` and will compare them. If both bits are set to `1`, the result will be a `1`, else it will be `0`.

To give you short example: if we perform this comparison between `1011` and `1100`, the result would be `1000` because just the left bit is `1` for both numbers. Coming back to `0xFFFFFFF`, the binary presentation of this number is consisting of just 28 bits. An integer like the one returned by the hashfunction is consisting of 32 bits.

If you now perform a bitwise AND, the left 4 bits are ignored because `0xFFFFFFF` is missing the first 4 bits and therefore they filled with zeros and the result of the comparison will be `0`. The rest stays the same since there is always a one in the second number. The first bit is used to indicate whether the number is positive or negative and this value gets lost. So it's set to `0` and therefore the whole number is positive.

The disadvantage here is that the following three bits are also lost. If you want to keep them, you would have to set the first number to `0` and the rest to `1`, so instead of `0xFFFFFFF` you would use `0x7FFFFFFF`.