# How to handle negative values of hashCode() when using it for file writing

Tags: java, hash

I'm making a program where a hashing of a string is used to decide a write location in a file. Here's how the location is calculated:

```
private long getWriteLocation(String s){ 

    long hash = s.hashCode()%FILESIZE;

    hash = hash*FILEENTRYSIZE;

    return hash;
}
```

the problem with this is that `hashCode()` can produce negative values. This leads to a crash since I'm using the output of the function as a write location to file:

```
ptr = getWriteLocation();
dictionaryFile.seek(ptr); // crashes if ptr is negative
```

My question is how to solve this problem. Should I take the absolute value of the hashcode? Or will I cause problems regarding randomness of the hash (I suspect I will be halving the output space), etc, by doing so? Is there a better way?

**NOTE:**
With hashing there is always the possibility of collisions. Thus, I'm handling collisions by jumping a fixed number of slots in the file until I find a free slot.

Comment: What is a problem you are solving?

Comment: See clarification.

Comment: That is not what he asked for. He means: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ... in other words: as expressed in my answer, you are most likely asking the wrong question.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash isn't *random*. Over-simplified, it is nothing but a numeric value computed "over" some data ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for example ).

In that sense: by using `Math.abs()` you are first of all increasing the likelihood of **collisions**.

In other words: your whole idea sounds like the wrong approach. Because depending on the number of strings to store, and that FILESIZE constant, you sooner or later (inevitably!) will encounter two different strings being put in the same spot.

Thus: *if* your requirement is to **always** store *different* strings in *different* slots then **hashing** can't work for you. If that requirement is *not* important for you, then sure, `Math.abs()` "fixes" your exception.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. So can I get a hash function that only outputs positive numbers?

Comment: @Sahand Again: if your requirement is that **different** strings never end up with the same value, then *hashing* is the **wrong** answer. If that requirements is "not your problem", then using Math.abs() would be fine.

Comment: @Sahand - Create your own class and you will have a full control of its hashing algorithm. Most likely you are going in the wrong direction though.

Comment: It is okay to have collisions, I'm handling them.

Comment: @Sahand Then, as said, abs() should help. But I agree with PM here - you *might* want to also use your own complete own hash function implementation then.

Comment: thanks guys. One final thing though about abs(), according to this answer, abs can cause negative values too. So is it really a valid solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219672/3128156